# Open .mol files and compiling information

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to create a program that opens a lot of files (.mol), and copies specific information from those files and saves it into a spreadsheet (TAB delimited files '\t').

I have 10000 mol files on my computer that look like SN00000001 SN00000002 SN00000003 ... SN00010000.

(download link => http://bioinf-applied.charite.de/supernatural_new/src/download_mol.php?sn_id=SN00000001)

I have two questions:

1. I already tried to use function load.molecules (rcdk) and ChemmineR (loadsdf) but I did not succeed to open a .mol file in R.
2. It´s possible to open each .mol file and save specific information such as "ID", "Name", "Molecular Formula" it into a unique spreadsheet using R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I will send you the code

```
# get the full path of your mol files
mol_files <- list.files(path = file.path(getwd(), "/Users/189919604/Desktop/Download 
SuperNatural II/SN00000001"), # specify your folder here
                    pattern = "*mol",
                    full.names = TRUE)

# create tibble, with filenames (incl. the full path)
df <- tibble(filenames = mol_files)

# create function to extract all the information 
extract_info <- function(sdfset) {
  # function to extract information from a sdfset (ChemmineR)
  # this only works if there is one molecule in the sdfset

  ID <- sdfset@SDF[[1]]@datablock["SNID"]
  Name <- sdfset@SDF[[1]]@header["Molecule_Name"]
  Molecular_Formula <- sdfset@SDF[[1]]@datablock["Molecular Formula"]

  sdf_info <- tibble(SNID = ID,
                 Name = Name,
                 MolFormula = Molecular_Formula)

  return(sdf_info)
}

# read all files and extract info
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(sdf_data = map(.x = filenames,
                        .f = ~ read.SDFset(sdfstr = .x)),
         info = map(.x = sdf_data,
                    .f = ~ extract_info(sdfset = .x)))

# make a nice tibble with only the info you want
all_info <- df %>% 
  select(molecule) %>% 
  unnest(info)

# write to file
write_delim(x = all_info,
            path = file.path(getwd(), "test.tsv"),
            delim = "\t")
```

Comment: I think the error is here `select(molecule)` should be `select(info)`

Comment: I tried that, but the file remains empty. I used notepad to open .tsv file, is that correct?

Comment: You can use any text editor. The ‘select(info)’ is the correct one. This function selects the ‘info’ column from the tibble. I’am doubting if any files are read. Does ‘mol_files’ contain all your filenames? Is the folder you specified correct? Do your mol files have extension .mol? In my case the folder where the mol files are in is “/home/rico/r-stuff/temp”. This is made in the ‘file.path’ function. My mol files end in .mol.

Comment: I updated the answer a bit, to clarify how the path in `list.files` should be entered.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works, I only tested it with 2 mol files. I used `read.SDFset` from `ChemmineR` package to read all the mol files. The package `tidyverse` I use, is to work with tibbles. Tibbles are actually dataframes with some extra properties / functionalities.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ChemmineR)

# get the full path of your mol files
mol_files <- list.files(# specify your folder here in case of windows also add your drive letter e.g.: "c:/users/path/to/my/mol_files"
                        path = "/home/rico/r-stuff/temp",
                        pattern = "*mol",
                        full.names = TRUE)

# create tibble, with filenames (incl. the full path)
df <- tibble(filenames = mol_files)

# create function to extract all the information 
extract_info <- function(sdfset) {
  # function to extract information from a sdfset (ChemmineR)
  # this only works if there is one molecule in the sdfset

  ID <- sdfset@SDF[[1]]@datablock["SNID"]
  Name <- sdfset@SDF[[1]]@header["Molecule_Name"]
  Molecular_Formula <- sdfset@SDF[[1]]@datablock["Molecular Formula"]

  sdf_info <- tibble(SNID = ID,
                     Name = Name,
                     MolFormula = Molecular_Formula)

  return(sdf_info)
}

# read all files and extract info
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(sdf_data = map(.x = filenames,
                        .f = ~ read.SDFset(sdfstr = .x)),
         info = map(.x = sdf_data,
                    .f = ~ extract_info(sdfset = .x)))

# make a nice tibble with only the info you want
all_info <- df %>% 
  select(info) %>% 
  unnest(info)

# write to file
write_delim(x = all_info,
            path = file.path(getwd(), "temp", "test.tsv"),
            delim = "\t")
```

Comment: @Ricoderks...I was able to create the .tsv file, but it was empty. Do you know how I can select the information I need? Such as compound name, ID, molecular formula, etc?
Thanks again!

Comment: Was the dataframe in R also empty? I tested it for 2 mol files and the file contained two rows. Is it possible that you send me your code?